# React-query - how to check when refetching has been finished

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-query

I have a component where I am fetching data with react-query and setting initial form values:

```js
const { data: caseData, refetch, isRefetching } = useQuery({
  queryKey: `caseData-${caseId}`,
  queryFn: () => fetchCaseById(caseId),
  staleTime: Infinity,
});

if (!caseData) return "Loading"

<CaseForm initialValues={createInitialValues(caseData)} refetch={refetch}/>
```

Inside a `CaseForm` component I have a button that `onClick` triggers refetch function:

```
<Button
    type="button"
    loading={isRefetching}
    variant="secondary"
    onClick={() => refetch()}
    className="w-max"
    size="small"
>
    Reload
</Button>
```

I would like to only create initial values once after data is fetched first time on mount and later on `refetch`. I thought of lifting form values into context provider so that i can check state there. Something like this:

```
const { data: caseData, refetch, isRefetching } = api.getCaseData(caseId);

<Suspense fallback="Loading">
    <CaseForm initialValues={caseData} refetch={refetch}/>
</Suspense>
```

And then in `CaseForm`:

```js
const { caseFormValues, setCaseFormValues } = useCaseProvider();

useEffect(() => {
  if (!caseFormValues) setCaseFormValues(initialValues);
}, []);

const {
  handleSubmit,
  control,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm({
  defaultValues: caseFormValues ? caseFormValues : initialValues,
});
```

That can help me with initial values when data is being fetched for the first time, but how can I check if data has been refetched, once it is finished being refetched so that I can updated form values?
I can't use `isRefetching` since that only shows when data has started refetching. Not sure how can I check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

> I want to know when ***data has arrived** after refetch*, and ***only in case of a refetch***.

Well, the refetch() function returns a promise, so just do what you want after it completed. So inside that promise, you don't need to check condition whether this is a initial loading or the refetching.

```
// Callback of the refetching
const handleRefetch = () => {
  refetch().then(res => {
    setCaseFormValues(res?.data)  // updated data here

    // do whatever you want here...
  })
}

<Button
  type="button"
  loading={isRefetching}
  variant="secondary"
  onClick={handleRefetch}
  className="w-max"
  size="small"
>
  Reload
</Button>
```

---

**INITIAL ANSWER:**

You don't need to handle this yourself. `react-query` provides an option `enabled`.

`enabled` is `true` by default, which means the *query is triggered automatically by `react-query`*. You can set `enabled: false` to disable this automation, so that it will only run 1st time on mounting, then it only runs to get new data on the time you call `refetch()`.

---

One more thing, `react-query` has 3 different variables to tracking the fetching states, which are:

- `isLoading`:

  Is `true` if the query is in a **"hard" loading** state. This means there is no cached data and the query is currently fetching (`isLoading = true` only at the 1st query when component is mounted).
- `isFetching`:

  Is `true` whenever a request is in-flight, which *includes initial loading as well as background refetches*.

  Will be true if the query is currently fetching, including background fetching.
- `isRefetching`:

  Is true whenever a background refetch is in-flight, which does not include initial loading.

  Is the same as `isFetching && !isLoading`.

You can find more from the [docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/reference/useQuery).

Hope this can help!

Comment: I have disabled automatic refetching by setting ```staleTime``` to ```Infinity```, the problem is that I need to know when the refetch was made and with current state flags I am not sure how to get that?

Comment: I haven't clear about your case. Why do you need to check whether the refetch was made, instead of manage all refetches by yourself?

Comment: I am managing all refetches by myself, I just also would like to know when refetched data has been loaded, so that I can reset my form values.

Comment: Ah right, sorry for my misunderstanding.
As you said `isRefetching` only shows when data has started refetching, so how about using `isFetching`, cause it's true at all the fetching states (both initial loading and refetching).

Comment: I've read again, wanna confirm that is that the thing you want to check is the data after the refetch finished?

Comment: Yes, I want to know when data has arrived after refetch, and only in case of a refetch.

Comment: Hmm, refetch() returns a promise, so just do what you want after it completed. You can see the code in my updated answer above.

Comment: The first time I call refetch() the result of the promise is, {status: "loading"} and without the {data: ""}. So the very first time I call refetch and then result.data is undefined. How to solve this?

Comment: @JespervandenMunckhof did you solve an issue? I have the same problem and it's so confusing...